# Android devices not registering as subscribers on Pushwoosh,using phonegap app and JQM

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, pushwoosh

Android devices not registering, I followed the pushwoosh official tutorial but I can't get it to work. I provided Google project number,Pushwoosh APP ID and called the initPushwoosh function on  but I don't know why the devices are not registering automatically to the Pushwoosh application dashboard.
From the code I am using I load the initPushwoosh function at the start of the application to register devices automatically but it's not working. I'm building the app using jQuery Mobile Framework and building the app from PC with lastest cordova version.

My complete code and phonegap config.xml you can find at my github link: https://github.com/albpower/radiopendimi-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you expect people to go through your project and fix it. Most probably this is not going to happen.

What I would suggest is start with Pushwoosh demo sample and go from there!
This would be a good place to start: https://github.com/Pushwoosh/phonegap-3-sample-app

Comment: I know that but I was desperately asking for solution to fix this this sample is working but it needs to be builded with Phonegap Build on cloud I was trying building for android from PC but I didn't have success